# Modify Speedometer Needle with just CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to modify the needle rotation value with inline transform calc(%Metadata%)
I don't know if it could be possible with a formula in it?

The possible metadata values could be 0 to 100,
0 should be equivalent to -90deg
and 100 should be equivalent to 90deg

I want the metadata value which is 0 - 100 to be converted into a deg using calc, but I don't know-how.

```
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
    <span class="needle" style="transform:rotate(%metadata%);"></span>
</div>
```

```css
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid tomato;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
#logo .needle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="transform:rotate(-90deg);"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you are trying to do like this? https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/PoPGqmQ

Comment: That looks like the answer they're looking for, I’d post it

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the intended result is. What do you want the animation to be?

Comment: @Domino hi, I'm sorry about the confusion, I updated my question. Thank you,

Comment: @UdaraKasun hello, thank you for the answer but it is not i am looking for. Im sorry if my question is not clear enough but I updated my question. Basically, i am asking if its possible for converting the metadata (0-100) to degree(-90deg to 90deg) using calc. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS variables for this:

```css
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid tomato;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
#logo .needle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    transform-origin:bottom;
    transform:rotate(calc(var(--r)*1.8deg - 90deg));
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="--r:0"></span>
</div>
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="--r:20"></span>
</div>
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="--r:50"></span>
</div>
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="--r:80"></span>
</div>
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
 <span class="needle" style="--r:100"></span>
</div>
```

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.speedometer {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  border: 20px solid tomato;
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.speedometer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999999;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 5px 5px;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  bottom: 3px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--r)*1.8deg - 90deg));
}
```

```html
<span style="--r:0" class="speedometer"></span>
<span style="--r:20" class="speedometer"></span>
<span style="--r:50" class="speedometer"></span>
<span style="--r:80" class="speedometer"></span>
<span style="--r:100" class="speedometer"></span>
```